# Tool for HTML whole-page minification?

Tags: javascript, html, css, minify

I have a fairly stand-alone page, and I'd like to make it as small as possible: inline minimized Javascript and minimized CSS, and then minimize the HTML itself.  There's tools for each of these parts, but I'd like to avoid writing the glue for putting all of these together.  Open source would be ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try http://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/

*EDIT*

Although doing it will make the code reading part a lot more complex and as a result, debugging will be a big pain. Do it only after you have all the other required optimization in place.

Comment: Thanks; the only thing that doesn't handle is inlining scripts and styles (it minimizes only the scripts and styles that are already inlined).  If I can find a tool to do that then a simple pipe between the two will do it...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're going to find one tool that does all, but I've seen a few that do get a decent job done..... for me normally combined with other tools though.

http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/
Page speed is a firefox plugin, and is also an apache module

> When you run Page Speed against a page
>   referencing HTML files, it
>   automatically runs the Page Speed HTML
>   compactor (which will in turn apply
>   JSMin and cssmin.js to any inline
>   JavaScript and CSS) on the files and
>   saves the minified output to a
>   configurable directory

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Pretty Diff tool at http://prettydiff.com/?m=minify&html

You can also tell the tool to point to a given page with the s parameter, such as:

http://prettydiff.com/?m=minify&html&s=https://stackoverflow.com/